# want to send offline data online when user get internet connection in php

Tags: php, cookies, local-storage, offline-caching

beginner on php

i am creating a form in which, if user is offline and click on submit button, the data of form must store in cookies or if user is online and click on submit button, tha data of form must directly post online

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Come on, this isn't even a question.